# Group elements with same date in list in python in python

Tags: python

I have this list :

```
list = [datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27)]
```

I want to group elements with same date in list  , how to do this please ?

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37) , datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7) ]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22)]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

f = lambda x:x.date()
[[i for i in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)]
```

Output:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7)],
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22)],
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `itertools.groupby` like,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import datetime
>>> x
[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27)]
>>> s = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(x), lambda x: (x.year, x.month, x.day))]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> pprint.pprint(s)
[[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7)],
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22)],
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47)]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict.setdefault` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

data = [datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27)]
result = {}
for i in data:
    result.setdefault(i.strftime("%Y%m%d"), []).append(i)
print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 37),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 20, 16, 50, 7)],
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 16, 51, 47),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 51, 20),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 10, 58, 27)],
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 10, 53, 22)]]
```